# Controlling plot order for visual objects with multiple geometries in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want ggplot to plot in a specific order to control what is visible when objects overlap.  Each data row maps to a composite of 2 geometry layers - the particulars of the plot require this.  I've been using a loop to do this, but it's very slow.  I wonder if there's a better way?  e.g.

```
d = data.frame(x=c(1,5,2,2,4,2), y=c(1,1,4,3,3,5), grp=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(grp))) +
  geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

Each polygon line should plot with its polygon - so e.g. the red polygon's line should be obscured by blue's polygon.  Is there any way to achieve this without looping when both `geom_polygon` and `geom_line` use the same dataset?

---

**Edit:** looping methods..

Here are loop methods I've used.  Added a better dataset for comparing performance.  Both take about 5.6s to run on my machine.  By comparison the typical approach (`ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill=factor(grp))) + geom_polygon() + geom_line(size=1)`) takes 0.45s.

```
d = data.frame(x = sample(-30:30,99,rep=T) + rep(sample(1:100,33),each=3),
               y = sample(-30:30,99,rep=T) + rep(sample(1:100,33),each=3),
               grp = rep(1:33,each=3))

# Method 1 - for loop
p = ggplot()
for(g in unique(d$grp)){
  dat = subset(d, grp == g)
  p = p + geom_polygon(data=dat, aes(x, y, fill = factor(grp))) + 
    geom_line(data=dat, aes(x, y), size=1)
}
print(p)

# Method 2 - apply
ggplot() + lapply(unique(d$grp), FUN=function(g){
  dat = subset(d, grp == g)
  list(geom_polygon(data=dat, aes(x, y, fill = factor(grp))),
       geom_line(data=dat, aes(x, y), size=1))
})
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the problem you're facing has to do with the line. If you remove the geom_line() you get the desired result. Also, If you put the geom_line before the geom_polygon() you get what I think is your desired output

Comment: Can you show the for-loop you've been using?

Comment: @geotheory I'm sorry, I have no solution. The only idea I have is to create an extra polygon for each group that is slightly larger on the sides were you need the line, and plot those first in black and then overplot in color. However, I think this would take way more time to program/test than it takes to run the loop to generate your image.

Comment: @Heroka. Thanks but unless I misunderstand you that would still hit the same problem of how to fix the geometry plot order?

Comment: @geotheroy assuming that polygons get plotted in group-order, that doesn't seem to be a problem. (first plot all black polygons, then plot smaller colored polygons).

Comment: @Heroka please continue in [this chat room..](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96559/controlling-plot-order-for-visual-objects-with-multiple-geometries-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Wonder if @hadley can advise if any better method is possible or if we're stuck with the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I just used your code and changed the order of the layers in `ggplot2`
It looks like this

```
d = data.frame(x=c(1,5,2,2,4,2), y=c(1,1,4,3,3,5), grp=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group=grp)) +
   geom_line(size=1)+
   geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(grp)))
```

And the result is this one

[image]

Also notice that if you remove the `geom_line` call you produce the same result but without the border.

Comment: Sorry Matian that doesn't really help. You're just plotting all the lines before (so underneath) all the polygons. See how the blue-green polygon has lost part of the line..

Comment: I understand. As far as I can think right now, I would suggest dropping the line (it doesn't border the triangles anyway in the original example). I'll give it a second thought later. I'm thinking that geom_line might not be the best way to do it...maybe geom_segment

Comment: Yes the line is just a demo example. My visualisation does require 2 separate geometries.